# Firebase hosting, Webpack and caching issues

Tags: firebase, webpack, firebase-hosting

I'm using Webpack to build my React project, and I deploy it with Firebase hosting. It's a SPA, the `index.html` loads a single JS bundle, it all works great.

Except that sometimes, I get this error from some users:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token `<`
>
> File https://tribeez.com/aa298947341ff919a5feecdc7367a6145a4a7d87.js line 1
>   col 1 in [anonymous]

It means that the JS bundle returned some HTML instead, and that happens when the file does not exist, thus returning the content of my `index.html`.

My `firebase.json` is quite basic:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So I was thinking, it must be when a visitor's browser is trying to fetch an older version of the JS bundle, but how can this happen? How can it load an older version of `index.html` (from its cache then) but can not load its related JS bundle from its cache too?

Should I tell Webpack to always create the JS bundle with the same filename and let Firebase Hosting handle the caching? Or should I handle this differently?